# Add Extra Field_for in Nested form with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, nested-forms

I made form where I can make new `Entity` with all its data, and add new `Users` that are associated with that Entity using `Has_many :through` association.

Here is the problem. I want to be able to add extra User field `li` element with button "Add extra user". I can't find the way to do it. I'm not vary familiar with java-script.

/views/entities/_form.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for(@entity) do |f| %>  
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :number %>
        <%= f.number_field :number %>
    </div>

    Users:
    <ul>
      <%= f.fields_for :bonds do |b| %>
        <li>
          <div class="field">
            <%= b.label :_destroy %>
            <%= b.check_box :_destroy %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= b.select :user_id, User.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= b.label :label %><br>
            <%= b.number_field :lebal %>
          </div>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Is there a way I could generate extra `f.field_for :bonds` with unique id using button on page? And could it work also on edit page, where I use the same form?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can use Cocoon - https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon . Cocoon makes it easier to handle nested forms.

Comment: I will try it. Will I need to make a lot of changes in code? or i will be able to use old one with modifications?

Comment: You won't have to change a lot, rather add a few more things to make it work.

Comment: Thanks. Now i only need to figure out what html.slim is saying in samples :D if you will post your answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Cocoon](http://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). Cocoon makes it easier to handle nested forms.